# Strange error with canvas context getImageData function in Firefox 13

Tags: firefox, canvas, getimagedata

I have some canvas code that works great in safari and chrome, but fails in firefox.

The firefox console reads:

> [17:44:13.372] uncaught exception: [Exception... "Operation is not supported"  code: "9" nsresult: "0x80530009 (NotSupportedError)"  location: "http://REDACTED.js Line: 703"]

Firebug gives the slightly-more-useful-to-humans:

```
Operation is not supported
var data = ctx.getImageData(x,y,1,1);
```

I am indeed calling `.getImageData` on line 703.

I have read that similar errors have been reported with regards to origin policies. This project is hosted on a web server (not local), and I haven't loaded any images from a different domain and put them on the canvas. In fact, I get the error even if the canvas is blank.

The webkit-based browsers give me the pixel data as asked, what can be done about firefox? Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a pared-down test case reproducing the problem, possibly on http://jsfiddle.net or http://webdevout.net/test?

Comment: zzz. There was code that was relying on mouse events having .offsetX and .offsetY, which are undefined in firefox. These undefined values indirectly result in `x`, and `y` above being `NaN`... Passing `NaN` to .getImageData results in the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't pass `NaN` to .getImageData.